# Low rank Log rank conjecture

Tags: matrices, communication-complexity

What is known about log rank conjecture in special situations of $O(\log N)$ rank $0/1$ matrix of size $N\times N$? Is there at least a conditional result showing better than $O(\sqrt{\log N})$ bound?

Answer (score 6):

Not that I am aware of. This is unknown even for special cases, e.g. XOR functions.